# Excel MATCH() function always giving #N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Super simple match, looks like this:

```
=MATCH("Team", A1:A25,0)
```

The data in A1:A25 is imported from a text file. The cells are formatted as text.

If I go into the column and manually type "Team" into the cell that already says "Team", then it will work. But unless I manually type it in, it says #N/A.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Have you checked length of what is in that cell to see if it is 4? Is that is correct have you checked character by character that the ASCII codes line up? Sometimes what you see is not indicative of what is there. Fonts formats and non-printing characters can be deceptive.

Comment: Thanks for forcing me to do this. Extra space at the end of the name. All fixed.

Comment: No problem. Been there done that. Trailing spaces are common but I've gotten spreadsheets where question marks were formatted as dashes.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff, that could take some time to figure out!

Comment: @DougGlancy that's why I recommended asking Excel what ASCII codes are at each character index in the string. Pretty quick then!!

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems could be, that you have unwanted empty characters (I mean space) either before or after the word (so it is 'Team ' instead of 'Team').
Dirty workaround would be trimming text such as following:

```
{=MATCH("Team", TRIM(A1:A25),0)}
```

(Please make sure that you enter it as Array formula with Ctrl + Shift + Enter)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the data in A1:A25, here's what I would do as a test.

Insert a column B next to column A.

Cntl-Spacebar to highlight all of column B.

Make sure the field time is set to General, not text.

Then run a formula in column b:  =trim(A1) and paste it down.

This will make sure the field is trimmed (i.e. there are no blank spaces at the end of the word).

This may fix your issue.